# Type error when passing web3provider as a prop with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ethers.js

I'm trying to pass a Web3Provider as a prop to a hook with others, and I keep getting an error

Here's the code of how I get the provider

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
```

Then I have inside the return statement:

```
<Form provider={provider} />
```

And in the hook

```
export const Form = (provider: ethers.providers.Web3Provider) => {
```

Types should be the same, but I keep getting the error:

> (JSX attribute) Web3Provider.provider:
> ethers.providers.ExternalProvider
>
> Type 'Web3Provider' is not assignable to type 'ExternalProvider'.
> Types of property 'send' are incompatible. Type '(method: string,
> params: any[]) => Promise' is not assignable to type '(request: {
> method: string; params?: any[] | undefined; }, callback: (error: any,
> response: any) => void) => void'. Types of parameters 'method' and
> 'request' are incompatible. Type '{ method: string; params?: any[] |
> undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I have tried casting to any in the form, but then I get an error when calling a method I can call outside.